# Is there a way i can send an email to the Lead when a license record is created in LMA

Tags: appexchange, lma

I have a managed package and whenever someone installs a package i would like to send them a email. I cant use a workflow on License object as i would not get the email address of the lead on the license record.

In my lead object my leadsource comes up as Package installation when someone installs the package. I do have 3 managed packages which i manage from my isv org. So i am not sure which package has got installed. i wanted to send different emails based on which package was installed.

Is there a way i can write a trigger for LMA objects?

Answer (score 1):

The LMA is mostly a managed package that contains namespaced custom objects such as `sfLma__License__c` just like any other managed package. So yes you can add triggers or do other customisation.